# Simplify old RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have old RegExp in java script that needs to be simplified.

```
new RegExp("(<A[^<>]*?(href)\\s*=\\s*['\"])("+_41+")(\\#[^'\"]*?['\"][^>]*?>)",
```

I am not very good in RegEx. Any help appreciated.

```js
function RadCleanAnchorsFilter(){
this.GetHtmlContent=function(_3f){
var _40=_3f;
var _41=document.location.href;
var re=new RegExp("(<A[^<>]*?(href)\\s*=\\s*['\"])("+_41+")(\\#[^'\"]*?['\"][^>]*?>)","ig");
_40=_40.replace(re,"$1$4");
return _40;
};
}
```

Comment: What is the regex trying to match and what is it trying to replace it with?

Comment: So, this tries to change all anchor tags that match the current URL? Wouldn't it be simpler to parse as HTML, then use the DOM API to look them up and change them?

Comment: To elaborate on VLAZ's comment (if that is what you're trying to do with this regex): look into the DOMParser interface.

Comment: I am not sure what this is do, as I am trying to fix the issue with security scan on existing application. The scan complains about Client ReDos: "ReDoS (regular expression denial of service) can use complex patterns to cause a denial of service (DoS). With certain patterns, processing time can grow exponentially in relation to input size. An attacker can use these regular expressions to cause the application to spend a significant amount of computation time processing a regular expression over a data-set, causing the application to hang." one of suggestions is to simplify the RegEx